# Delete node from Binary Search Tree- Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

my deletion code for the binary search tree is giving me a Segmentation fault, and I was wondering what the problem was.

The pre-order: 64 8 4 32 16 128 512 256
and the steps run are

removing 4

removing 64

removing 128

and it should result in   pre-order: 256 8 32 16 512

but I am getting  pre-order: 256 8 0 32 16 512 9502512

my code is below

```
 bool IntBST::remove(int value){
     Node* n = getNodeFor(value, root);
 if(n == NULL){
     return false;
}

    else{
            if((n->right == NULL) && (n->left == NULL)){
                    if(n->parent->left == n){
                          n->parent->left == NULL;
                  }
                    else{
                            n->parent->right == NULL;
                    }
                    delete n;
                     return true;
             }
             if(n->left && (n->right == NULL)){
                     n->parent->left = n->left;
                     n->left->parent = n->parent;
                     n->left =NULL;
                     delete n;
                    return true;
                             }
            if(n->right && (n->left == NULL)){
                    n->parent->right = n->right;
                     n->right->parent = n->parent;
                     n->right =NULL;
                     delete n;
                    return true;
                    }
             else{
                    Node* n2 = getSuccessorNode(n->info);
                    int temp = n2->info;
                    remove(n2->info);
                    n->info = temp;
                     delete n2;
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you delete a different node in the last case and not the one you searched for?  Also, what is parent pointing to for the top node?

Comment: parent is pointing to NULL in the top node, and I was deleting the successor node because I'm supposed to switch the values r

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single step through your code *watching* values of variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.  Also, draw the node and links as you debug the tree operations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't given us enough to reproduce the error, and the failure case seems too complicated. Do you still get the error if you omit the 12? What if you don't remove the 4? *Simplify.*